# Return change with certain number of coins

Tags: java

I want to implement an automatic coffee vending machine.  The machine is pre-filled with coins (for instance 10 5-cent coins, 20 10-cent coins, etc).

I want the user to enter a certain amount (insert money) subtract the price of the coffee (e.g 120 cents) and then give change back based on the coins available in the vending machine.

I started like this:

```
final int [] coins = {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5};
```

...but how can I give them a value like 10 = 5 cause there are 5 10-cent coins?

Comment: 2 quick possibilities are: 1) 2 arrays (one with coin value, the second with amount of coins in the machine), or 2) a hash (key being coin value, and value being amount of coins).

Comment: I suggest you tag this question with #algorithm, you may get more attention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CoinDispenser {
    private final Map<Coin, Integer> coinCount = getDefaultMap();

    public void addCoins(Coin type, int amount) {
        coinCount.put(type, amount + getCoinCount(type));
    }

    public int getCoinCount(Coin type) {
        return coinCount.get(type);
    }

    // Why not use an empty map you ask? Map.get will return null
    // if the key does not exist. So for the default map we get all
    // the possible coins and add them to the map with the default
    // count of zero
    private static Map<Coin, Integer> getDefaultMap() {
        Map<Coin, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
        for (Coin c: Coin.values())
            ret.put(c, 0);
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Get the change in the available coins. Please note that
     * this removes the coins from the vending machine.
     */
    public Map<Coin, Integer> getChange(int amount) {
        Map<Coin, Integer> ret = getDefaultMap();

        if (getChangeImpl(amount, true, getDefaultMap())) {// if we have the right coins...
            getChangeImpl(amount, false, ret);// do the real thing
            return ret;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient coins!!");// fall through case
    }

    /** The private version of get change...
     *
     * @param amount The amount of change needed
     * @param isMock If true, this will not remove coins from the dispenser
     * @param out The output map
     * @return True, if we have the proper coins
     */
    private boolean getChangeImpl(int amount, boolean isMock, Map<Coin, Integer> out) {
        List<Coin> types = Arrays.asList(Coin.values());// get the coin types, in least to greatest order...
        Collections.reverse(types);// flip the array because we need the big coins to go first
        int amountLeft = amount;// how much change do we still need to make up?

        for (Coin c: types)
            while (amountLeft >= c.value && getCoinCount(c) > 0) {// while the coin is the right
                                                                    // value and we still have it
                amountLeft -= c.value;// de-inc amountLeft by the coins value
                out.put(c, out.get(c) + 1);// add the coin to the out
                if (isMock == false)// if this is the real thing
                    addCoins(c, -1);// remove one coin from inventory
            }


        return amountLeft == 0;// if we don't have the correct coins, this won't be zero
    }

    // This belongs in it's own file
    public enum Coin {
        Penny       (1),// each coin and it's value
        Nickle      (5),
        Dime        (10),
        Quarter     (25),
        HalfDollar  (50);

        /**
         * The value of the coin in cents.
         */
        public final int value;

        Coin(int value) {this.value = value;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinDispenser vm = new CoinDispenser();
        vm.addCoins(Coin.Penny, 45);
        vm.addCoins(Coin.Dime, 3);
        vm.addCoins(Coin.Quarter, 1);

        System.out.println(vm.getChange(36));// 1 quarter, 1 dime, 1 penny
        System.out.println(vm.getChange(36));// 2 dimes, 6 pennies
        System.out.println(vm.getChange(36));// 36 pennies
        System.out.println(vm.getChange(36));// IllegalArgumentException: Not enough coins!!
    }
}
```

### How I got here

**Step 1:** What are the requirements? You should be able to

- Add coins and
- Remove coins

from a coin dispenser.

**Step 2:** Start codeing!!

First off you need to figure out how you would represent the coins. IMO the best way is to use a `Coin` `enum` and a map of type `<Coin, Integer>` to store the coins. Example of the `Coin` enum:

```
public enum Coin {
    Penny       (1),// each coin and it's value
    Nickle      (5),
    Dime        (10),
    Quarter     (25),
    HalfDollar  (50);

    /** The value of the coin in cents. */
    public final int value;

    Coin(int value) {this.value = value;}
}

Map<Coin, Integer> coinCount = new HashMap<>();
```

(if you aren't familiar with `enum`s, each entry is basically named final static instance of the class)

So, now that we have a way to store the coins, we'll create a class to wrap and manipulate this data. `CoinDispenser` sounds like a good name.

```
public class CoinDispenser {
    private final Map<Coin, Integer> coinCount = new HashMap<>();

    public enum Coin {...}
}
```

Now we can start adding functionality. Starting simple, an `addCoins` and `getCoinCount` function sound good.

```
public class CoinDispenser {
    private final Map<Coin, Integer> coinCount = getDefaultMap();

    public void addCoins(Coin type, int amount) {
        coinCount.put(type, amount + getCoinCount(type));
    }

    public int getCoinCount(Coin type) {
        return coinCount.get(type);
    }

    // We can't start with an empty map
    private static Map<Coin, Integer> getDefaultMap() {
        Map<Coin, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
        for (Coin c: Coin.values())
            ret.put(c, 0);
        return ret;
    }

    public enum Coin {...}
}
```

Pretty simple, right? Time to move on the the next method, `getChange(int amount)`. The algorithm for this method is pretty simple, get rid of the big coins fist. This is v1:

```
public Map<Coin, Integer> getChange(int amount) {
    List<Coin> types = Arrays.asList(Coin.values());
    Collections.reverse(types);

    Map<Coin, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
    fillWithDefault(ret);
    int amountLeft = amount;

    for (Coin c: types) {
        while (amountLeft >= c.value && getCoinCount(c) > 0) {
            amountLeft -= c.value;
            ret.put(c, ret.get(c) + 1);
            addCoins(c, -1);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Basically we get all the coin types, sort them in least to greatest order, and create a map to be filled with the change returned. Next we iterate through all the coins and check each coin to see if it will work (it's value is less than the amount left and we have the coin in inventory), if it will work we de-inc the amount left by the coins value, add the coin to the return, and remove it from the innovatory. But there's a bug. What happens when you try to overdraw?

Zero coins are returned in the map! Why? We never check the `amountLeft` var in `getChange`. Amount left is not `0` when it returns because we don't have enough coins in inventory. The fix is to split this method into 2 methods, one checks to see if we have enough coins, the other to remove the coins. This is what it looks like:

```
public Map<Coin, Integer> getChange(int amount) {
    Map<Coin, Integer> ret = getDefaultMap();
    if (getChangeImpl(amount, false, getDefaultMap())) {// if we have the right coins...
        getChangeImpl(amount, true, ret);// Do the real thing
        return ret;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient coins!!");// fall through case
} 

private boolean getChangeImpl(int amount, boolean isMock, Map<Coin, Integer> out) {    
    ...
    for (Coin c: types)
        while (amountLeft >= c.value && getCoinCount(c) > 0) {
            ...
            if (isMock == false)// if this is the real thing
                addCoins(c, -1);// remove one coin from inventory
        }
    return amountLeft == 0;// if we have the correct coins, this will be zero
}
```

We have one last bug. Let's say that we have `1 Quarter` and `5 Dimes`, then we try to draw `50` cents, it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient coins!!")`. If you walk through the logic of `getChangeImpl`, this makes sense, because we try to draw the big coins first - `Quarter` in this case - and we draw one, so that we have `5 Dimes` and no `Quarters` to make up `25 Cents`. I leave this one as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: thanks for your answer im gonna have a closer look at this tomorrow but so far this seems pretty good.

So if the customer would insert a dollar it would be something like:

if (readInt("insert coins here: ") == 100){
vm.addCoins(Coin.Dollar, 1);
}
?

Comment: Yes, or any combination of coins that equals one dollar. If you want to add a `Dollar` coin, you would have to change the `HalfDollar  (50);` line of the `Coin` enum to `HalfDollar  (50), Dollar(100);` because the entries of `Coin` **MUST** be in order, otherwise the logic in `getChange` would no longer be valid.

Comment: It's an answer, it has code, but it doesn't explain *why* it's a good answer.  Nor does it explain what steps you took to deliver on the actual requirements.  I'm sure this code works, but it does little to teach; it only encourages active copy and paste.

Comment: @Makoto Does that help? I added explanation.

Comment: Slightly.  It gives a lot more in the way of explanation (which is enough for me to remove my downvote), but it feels like it's a bit...much.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but I can't think of many places to slim down.

Comment: @Makoto sorry to bother you about it again, but does this help?

Answer (score 3):

You could store them in a Map - for example [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Then you would use value of the coin as the key and amount as the value.
for example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> coins = new HashMap<>();
coins.put(10, 5); //5 10-cent coins
```

To get amount of 10-cent coins you would just do:

```
coins.get(10);
```

Comment: Thought about that but can i overwrite the value ?
e.g coins.put (10, 4); 
after the machine gave one 10 ct coin out or is there a smarter way to overwrite/edit

Comment: Yes, if the machine gave out one 10 ct you would do 
coins.put(10, coins.get(10) - 1);

Comment: Thank you im gonna try that out then !